# Match two images keypoints

Tags: python, opencv

How can I match features of two images without using opencv matchers ? I've detected keypoints and descriptors for them.

```
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)
```

If I understand correctly I should compare each descriptor from des1 with each from des2 and find best. But how i can compare them ?

Comment: have you thought of finding the Euclidean distance between `des1` and `des2`? You can use `np.linalg.norm(des1 - des2)` from numpy module.

Comment: just use the descriptor mat entries. E.g. match = lowest sum of squared distances from one descriptor to each of the other image would be some kind of brute force matcher.

Comment: just use the descriptor mat entries. E.g. match = lowest sum of squared distances from one descriptor to each of the other image would be some kind of brute force matcher.

Comment: you could write your own opencv matcher class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIFT descriptor of a point is just 128-dimensional vector, so you can simple compute Euclidean distance between every two and match nearest pairs.

From opencv SIFT you get arrays `des1` and `des2` which are arrays of SIFT vectors for each point. You can compute distance between every pair by numpy broadcasting like that:

```
distance = np.sqrt(np.sum((des1[:, np.newaxis, :] - des2[np.newaxis, :, :]) ** 2, axis=-1))
```

Now in every row of `distance` you have Euclidean distance between particular keypoint from `kp1` and every keypoint from `kp2`.

This approach is simple, but often not very effective. If you want to implement some more complicated matcher by yourself, you should read some SIFT papers for this.

I've found such two:

[paper 1 - simpler](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~cipolla/lectures/4F12/Slides/old/4F12-SIFT-extra-material.pdf)

[paper 2 - more complicated](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~silvio/teaching/EECS598/lectures/lecture10_1.pdf)